# Timec Complexity O-Notation for Kociemba, Korf, and Thistlethwaite's Algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, rubiks-cube

I'm currently studying the cube-solving algorithms developed by Kociemba, Korf, and Thistlethwaite and I'm interested in understanding their computational complexities.

Could someone please explain or provide the Big O notation for the time complexity of these algorithms?

Any insights or resources on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Are you asking for the time complexity to solve an $n\times n\times n$ cube?

Comment: Hi, no 3x3x3 cube